# Excel equivalent of Google Sheets Range A2:A

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

Is there an Excel equivalent for Google's `A2:A` other than `A2:A1048576`, i.e. without specifying the last row number explicitly and keeping the formula as concise as possible?

Comment: Maybe something like `A2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("ZZZ",A:A))`

Comment: Or use a table. Also, a lot of functions can take entire column references without issue as they ignore anything outside the used range.

Comment: If A1 won't cause an issue then I use "A:A" often but if someone dumps data below then it gets included...